# What will happen if a Django request gets to long?

Tags: asp.net, django, asynchronous, synchronization, microservices

I am trying to figure out a microservices architecture for my Django Restfull webapp.This Engineering app will envolve with heavy mechanical and geometrical calculations in some places. Due to the Django's slow (actually python's) calculation nature I will make main app with Django(because of its killer nice features) and also I want to design microservices as side functions on C# asp.net(due to its calculation power). This will allow me through heavy calculations on it so I can keep Django main app just like a bridge. So my questions;

1. When Django main app sends a request to microservice What will happen if a calculation gets too long on microservice? Lets say 10sec, will my whole app be frozen along the 10sec.?
2. I want to use async fuctions on ASP.NET, will it negatively effect the sync Django main app?

Answer (score 0):

@Issac v- For long-running processes, you shouldn't do it in the request-response thread. You should use a message queue like RabbitMQ and use celery to do it asynchronously. This will free up the request-response thread. E.g Image processing, file processing, etc. You can do heavy computations in python too. Python has all you need for computation. I have used Python and OpenCV for heavy image processing. It's up to you how you design your service.

Additionally, in a microservice architecture, have you thought of using something like pub-sub design instead of Http request-response. Service to service interaction is ideal for publishing-subscribing architecture.

And my 2cent, You can do everything with Django. Django has everything you need.You might not need asp.net